# Dell Latitude XT2 wireless driver and touchscreen settings keep reverting

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, touchscreen

I am new to Ubuntu and using a Dell Latitude XT2. When Installed Ubuntu there was a problem with my wireless drivers. After looking around a bit I managed to fix it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

with a wired internet connection.

My touchscreen was also causing me problems so I tried to turn it off with:

```
xinput set-prop 'N-Trig MultiTouch' 'Device Enabled' 0
```

which again works.

My problem is everything reverts when I turn my laptop off so I am currently having to do this every time I turn it on. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `lspci -knn | grep -A2 Net` command?

Comment: Sure, its: '00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0252]
 Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
 Kernel driver in use: wl'

Comment: I do not have any idea about your problem with touchscreen, sorry. But, I think it is better to ask touchscreen problem in a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Ubuntu bcm43xx [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) you should install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer package and use b43 module. So, first thing to do is to remove firmware-b43-installer and bcmwl-kernel-source packages. For this, give

`sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source firmware-b43-installer`

command. Then give

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`

command. After installing the pacakges, load b43 module by

`sudo modprobe b43`

command and you wireless card should work. If it does not work after rebooting computer, try to find out whether b43 module is blacklisted or not by looking files in /etc/modprobe.d/ folder. You can try

`grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`

command. If the output is similar to

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist b43`

, open that file

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/file_name`

and remove `blacklist b43` line.

Comment: Thanks, i already tried the first three steps. I have done them again and they didnt work. The output i get from `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*` is `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb. /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist b43` So i opened the file you mentioned to remove the line you suggested but the file is empty.

Comment: File's being empty is strange. Are you sure that you opened the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file?

Comment: Sorry, I realised that I forgot to remove firmware-b43-installer package, so I updated my answer.

Comment: The output I am getting from `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*` is now: `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf~:blacklist b43
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf~:blacklist b43legacy
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf~:# replaced by b43 and ssb.` so i am entering this:`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf` but its empty. The `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` isnt empty so i deleted the line you said and nothing has happened.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For people with the same touchsceen problem you can quickly create a start up program to disable the touchscreen each time you log in:
Open terminal and type:

```
cd
gedit notouch
```

then put:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-prop 'N-Trig MultiTouch' 'Device Enabled' 0
```

into the text file and save it.

back in the terminal type:

```
chmod 744 notouch
```

Then navigate to your start up applications (Search Startup Applications in your dash) and add:

```
Name: Touch Off
Command: /home/username/notouch
Comment: Turns off touch
```

This will then run each time you startup you computer and disable the touchscreen.

For original answer (where i found it) see here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1600818&page=2